# how get all existing users data with their other field datas using wordpress

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I tried to get all users data using `get_user_meta` WordPress method

```
$userid = get_current_user_id();
$usr = get_userdata($userid);
$usr_meta = get_user_meta($userid);
$all_users = get_user_meta();

print_r($all_users);
```

But when I try it with `user_id` it success to return data. But without `user_id` it returns nothing.

I want to get all wordpress users with their field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get_users():Retrieve list of users matching criteria.**

**get_user_meta() : Retrieve user meta field for a user.**

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user_id){
        print_r(get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID));
    }
```

Comment: I already got a user data but my problem is getting all users data.

Answer (score 1):

**[WordPress](https://wordpress.org/)** does not have any direct built-in function to retrieve all user meta data.

You can you these two pre-defined wordpress function to get your expected result.

- [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)

  - This will help you to get all fileds related to users. e.g ID
- [get_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)

  - This will retrive all the meta information of specified user id

So here is code snippet for you.

```
// Get all user ids
$users = get_users(array('fields' => array('ID')));

// Looping through all user ids and create all user meta information
$all_users = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
    $all_users[$user->ID] = get_user_meta($user->ID);
}
print_r($all_users);
```